# How to change stripe payments elements css

Tags: css, payment-gateway, stripe

I have integrated **Stripe payment system**. Now I wanted to change the card number input fields css. The problem is these fields come under iframe tag. But until iframe loads, I cannot access these. I tried jquery

> on load

but it does not work.